# Lock multiple cells in Google Spreadsheets with absolute reference ($)

Tags: google-sheets, absolute

Is there anyway to add a `$` in front of all the cell references for formulas in my Google Spreadsheets without hand typing them in?

> Ex: =Sheet1!H164 -> =Sheet1!$H$164

I have hundreds of formulas I need to do this for. I understand that <kbd>F4</kbd> is a hotkey, but it would take years to lock the cell references that way.

Answer (score 1):

For a column of formulae such as you show, select the column, Edit, Find and Replace..., Find !H. Replace with !$H$, check Also search within formulae and Done. Need to watch the likes of Wow!How was that possible but an entire sheet this way rarely takes a lot of Find/Replace, if reasonably well-structured.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend to use Find and replace (e.g. Find !A. Replace with !$A$)

But attention: If your sheet has entries in more than 26 columns, you would affect columns after Z, e.g. AA1 would become $A$A1 which will fail. You have to go through them afterwards manually and correct.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use the [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) formula.

Let's take an easy example. We want to apply `=$A$1` to the entire a row.

Replace `=$A$1` with `=indirect("$A$"&row(A1))`.

The [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) formula can be dragged down as far as you want or combined with [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) to do it automatically e.g.

```
=arrayformula(indirect("$A$"&row(A1:A100)))
```

(if you want to apply absolute referencing up to the row 100).