# What's the shortcut to apply absolute reference to a cell in Google Sheets on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-sheets

I want my cell B12 to be anchored using absolute reference. So it needs to become $B$12.

According to this answer: [Shortcut to anchor a cell in Google Sheets + Chrome + Mac + 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766435/shortcut-to-anchor-a-cell-in-google-sheets-chrome-mac-2020)

And also according to the official documents from Google sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110#zippy=%2Cmac-shortcuts

The shortcut for applying absolute reference (or "anchoring") to a cell in Google Sheets on a Mac is: **fn + f4**

However, on my Mac this isn't working...

Could someone please provide a solution so that I can anchor multiple cells at once in my Google Sheet?

I have a lot of cells that need to be anchored like this, and doing it manually will take a lot of time.

**NB**: I'm not looking for this solution where you use find and replace. It's a workaround, not a solution. [Lock multiple cells in Google Spreadsheets with absolute reference ($)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659641/lock-multiple-cells-in-google-spreadsheets-with-absolute-reference)

---

EDIT:

I've found out that **fn + f4** does work when you're *inside* the formula editor.

This was not exactly what I'm looking for, as I still cannot bulk edit multiple cells. But it seems that this is the only thing that's possible.

Comment: Have you tried just using f4?

Comment: Pressing fn + f4 equals pressing f4. I've also tried pressing simply f4 after editing the Apple settings so that you can directly press f4 without holding the fn button. Doesn't work either.  See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204436

Comment: gotcha, it's the same on PC, just wanted to make sure since you never know. The question is the equivalent to "have you tried restarting" from tech support. I'm not a mac user myself so won't be able to help, but good luck. I can understand how frustrating this is. Does f2 work to open the formula though?

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem with my Mac but found a solution. When creating an absolute reference, you have to put your cursor between the cell column letter and cell row number within the cell formula and then press fn + F4.  So,  =SUM(B5....  to make the "B5" an absolute reference you would need to put your cursor between the B and 5 and then press fn + F4.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In Google Sheets, I was able to "find and replace" cases that matched the pattern:
exclamation mark followed by letter(s) and number(s)

!(\w+?)(\d+)

and used the replacement expression to include the exclamation mark and add the $ symbols before the letters and before the numbers, converting the relative references into absolute.

!$$$1$$$2

I think the google doc was suggesting to use \ before $ in the replacement that included backreferences, but I had to use $ to escape the symbol instead of using \ to escape it.

The above worked, this did not: !\$$1\$$2

I was able to convert 115 instances of relative cell references into absolute cell references.

='Aggregated Cert Projections'!K9

became

='Aggregated Cert Projections'!$K$9

Comment: This saved me SO much time. TYTY